# How to intercept HTTP calls from an application?

Tags: c#, http, profiling

I want to watch all the HTTP requests going out of a certain application and cancel them if needed.

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can touch the system's proxy configuration (which is used by many applications) or, if the app doesn't heed that setting, touch the application's configuration to use a proxy of your choice, you can create a [HTTP proxy](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/) that would do the job for you.

If you just want to profile, there is a ready made tool that behaves like this and is very nice, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/).

Else you'd have to go deeper into the network stack and implement something like a sniffer/firewall, for instance using [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/). That's a lot harder to do.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with Windows, it is possible to hook the WinInet API calls and do whatever you want with them.

[FreeCap](http://www.freecap.ru/eng/) (or its commercial version, WideCap) does that: allows you to send TCP traffic through a proxy server. That proxy might then do the filtering (e.g. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/)).

I know this brings more stand-alone applications into the system, but it works.